# _stext and _etext in the 2.6 Linux kernel - why can't my kernel module link to them?

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel, driver

I have a kernel module that needs to have access to the kernel's `_stext` and `_etext` symbols. For some reason, even though the kernel has definitions for these symbols (`/proc/kallsyms`), whenever I load my module I get

```
mymodule: Unknown symbol _etext (err 0)
mymodule: Unknown symbol _stext (err 0)
```

I'm not running a tainted kernel, and everything else in the module seems to link ok. Are there module or license restrictions on linking to `_stext` and `_etext`? Is there a substitute definition in the kernel that I could use for the beginning and end of code memory?

Update:

I'm looking at the kernel source, and in `kallsyms.c`, there's this:

```
static int read_symbol_tr(const char *sym, unsigned long long addr)
{
size_t i;
struct text_range *tr;

for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(text_ranges); ++i) {
    tr = &text_ranges[i];

    if (strcmp(sym, tr->stext) == 0) {
        tr->start = addr;
        return 0;
    } else if (strcmp(sym, tr->etext) == 0) {
        tr->end = addr;
        return 0;
    }
}

return 1;
}
```

Does this mean that the `_etext` and `_stext` entries that I'm seeing the `/proc/kallsyms` are fake symbols that a kernel module can't actually link to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel module linker will only link symbols that have been "exported" via an additional mechanism: the symbol must be exported with `EXPORT_SYMBOL()` or `EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL()`. (The `_GPL` variant indicates that the kernel developers are labeling that an *internal* interface and thus available only to GPL-licensed code.) I cannot find exports for either `_stext` or `_etext` on my kernel sources, so I don't believe they are available to you to use.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ah - yes - I began to suspect as much. As for what I'm trying to accomplish, I'm working with a 2.6.37 kernel put together by someone else in a device NAND. For some of the work that I'm doing, I need oprofile. They didn't build oprofile into it, nor did they include many of the oprofile dependancies like CONFIG_PROFILING.

Comment: ...I can build my own kernel with their config parameters, but getting it onto their NAND seems to be a problem. I can also build a similar kernel but with a module-ized oprofile, but the kernel doesn't have many of the oprofile dependancies in it, and the dependancies can't be easily module-ized. So for my work I've been hacking together a Frankenstein-creation oprofile module with some of the necessary dependancies built in.

Comment: Wow, my condolences, that's a frustrating long way to go just to get some profiling data. Good luck!